# Euler's method for a 2nd order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, core-language

This is my first post on this site. Also, I'm new to *Mathematica*.

I'm trying to solve my first problem with *Mathematica*. It's about solving a 2nd order differential equation. I dont have the explicit `F[t]` instead I have a list of values for `{t, F[t]}`

```
 {{0, 1.00799}, {0.1, 1.09268}, {0.2, 1.18921}, {0.3, 1.25086}, {0.4, 1.32473}, 
  {0.5, 1.36879}, {0.6, 1.39813}, {0.7, 1.41114}, {0.8, 1.39531}, {0.9, 1.3986}, 
  {1., 1.39468}}
```

The equation I want to solve is

```
n = 5
h = 0.1
i = 0
y[0] = 1
yy[0] = 1
zi[0] = Table[i, {i, {1, 1}}]
T1 = {{0, 1.00799}, {0.1, 1.09268}, {0.2, 1.18921}, {0.3, 
   1.25086}, {0.4, 1.32473}, {0.5, 1.36879}, {0.6, 1.39813}, {0.7, 
   1.41114}, {0.8, 1.39531}, {0.9, 1.3986}, {1., 1.39468}}
Tij = Table[T1[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 11}]
ij = Table[T1[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 11}]
F[t_] := {y[t], (Tij[[t + 1]] - 9*yy[t] - 13*y[t])/5}
While[i < n, zi[i + 1] = zi[i] + F[i]*h; y[i + 1] = h + i; 
 yy[i + 1] = zi[[2]]; i = i + 1]
```

Comment: Try again to paste your code. Do this: Put all your working code in one cell. Then do `Cell->ConvertTo->InputForm` (from the menu), then select the cell again and do RIGHT-CLICK (with the mouse), `COPY-AS->Plain text`. Then paste the result here again.

Comment: thx for that :)

Comment: I can't follow your code now. But noticed you wrote `zi[[2]]` there, and before you wrote `zi[0, 0]` You can't do this. `zi[[2]]` is trying to access position 2 in a list. You never allocated  a list of this size. `zi[2]` is different from `z[[2]]`. You can write `z[1000]` without having to allocate anything (this is called indexed variable), but you can't write `z[[1000]]` without first allocating the space, as this is an actual list or vector in Matlab talk.

Comment: I think thats the problem... how can i enter a indexed vector like in this case zi[0]={1,1}, the indexed seems that only admits a lonely value and not vectors. (like y[0]=1)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to work with your sampled points is to derive an interpolating function from it.

```
pts = 
  {{0, 1.00799}, {0.1, 1.09268}, {0.2, 1.18921}, {0.3, 1.25086}, {0.4, 1.32473}, 
   {0.5, 1.36879}, {0.6, 1.39813}, {0.7, 1.41114}, {0.8, 1.39531}, {0.9, 1.3986}, 
   {1., 1.39468}};
f = Interpolation[pts];
```

Given `f`, to solve your ODE with Euler's method implemented by a while-loop, you could use

```
yPts = {{0., 1.}}; v0 = 1.;
Module[{t = yPts[[1, 1]], dt = .05, a, v = v0, y = yPts[[1, 2]]},
   While[t <= 1.,
     a = (9/5) v - (13/5) y + f[t]/5;
     t += dt;
     v += a dt;
     y += v dt;
     yPts = {yPts, {t, y}}];
   yPts = Partition[Flatten[yPts], 2]];
```

Here is a plot of the results

```
yPlot = ListLinePlot[yPts, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: ode-1.png]

*Mathematica*, of course, can solve your ODE directly with `NDSolve`. It would be good to compare the above results with its more exact solution.

```
sol =
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == (9/5) y'[t] - (13/5) y[t] + f[t]/5, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1},
    y[t], {t, 0, 1}];
 y = Head[sol[[1, 1, 2]]];
 Show[yPlot, Plot[{y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ode-2.png]

The results from the Euler method code are not too bad.